# How to use two independent datasets in machine learning phd research work?

Tags: predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, ensemble-modeling, research

In order to develop an academic performance prediction model for a local Higher Ed Institution, I have collected the [OULAD open dataset](https://analyse.kmi.open.ac.uk/open_dataset) and the local Institution's dataset which I structured into the same file structure and feature formats as OULAD dataset. The objective of the research focuses on demographic features and performance-based features only, and I am trying to develop a multi-class classification ensemble model. However, I do not know how to use the two datasets, should I write individual research papers showcasing the performance of the ensemble approach on each of the datasets, or should i write a single comprehensive research paper where both the datasets are used?

Comment: Hi @AnilPHD, welcome to the site. This question is highly opinion-based and also very dependent on the context. You are likely the one that can answer it best.

Comment: Thanks Noe, its exciting for a newbie here to see a comment like this on his first question :)